# I have two file -> a.tex and b.tex,how to insert b.pdf after a.pdf?

Tags: pdfpages, include

```
%********a.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
Hello
\includepdf[pages=-]{b.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Now `b.tex`

```
%%%%%%%%%%
%********b.tex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
World!
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please ask your question in the body and not only at the title line.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want, since it seems to me that what you have written is a solution.

Comment: I want to write a book with 400 pages and my book have 4 part,i want to type the second part at first.at the end i want to unified 4 part.

Comment: This would lead to inconsistencies, most probably. Why do you not use the `\part{Book 1} ... \part{Book 4}` command? You can split your `TeX` code however to several `.tex` files and include them afterwards in any order you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used the syntax `\includepdf[<option>]{file.pdf}` so I probably ignore its advantages.

I specify the following because you mentioned in the title that you own tex sources of your files a.pdf and b.pdf.

Just editing the template from the previous answer by @Christian, I would suggest you use the command `\include{}`:

```
\begin{document}

\part{This is the 1st book}
\chapter{The first chapter of the first part}
\include{a}%% INCLUDE filename

\part{This is the 2nd book}

\chapter{The first chapter of the 2nd part}
\include{b1}%% INCLUDE filename

\chapter{The second chapter of the 2nd part}
\include{b2}%% INCLUDE filename

\end{document}
```

or the command `\input{}`:

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is the 1st book}
\chapter{The first chapter of the first part}
\input{a.tex}%% INPUT filename.tex

\part{This is the 2nd book}

\chapter{The first chapter of the 2nd part}
\input{b1.tex}%% INPUT filename.tex

\chapter{The second chapter of the 2nd part}
\input{b2.tex}%% INPUT filename.tex

\end{document}
```

to do the task. Differences between `input` and `include` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, this works as a 'kickstart' for the OP...

Change the title, styles at will ...

```
\documentclass{book}



\renewcommand{\partname}{Book}

% If chapters should be reset when a new part ('book') starts then
% use this code
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is the 1st book}
\chapter{The first chapter of the first part}


\part{This is the 2nd book}

\chapter{The first chapter of the 2nd part}

\chapter{The second chapter of the 2nd part}


\part{Book 3}

\chapter{The first chapter of the 3rd part}

\chapter{The second chapter of the 3rd part}


\part{Book 4}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table of contents of the book with subbooks]

Comment: .Thank you.but i think i could not ask my question   exactly!